# How does "lost me there" suits here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In comedy movie *Seeking a Friend for the end of the world*, Penny say this words to Dodge in car:

> Penny: My dry cleaner. Meatball subs at Zuzu's. Mmm.
>
> Dodge: Mmm. . . Mmm-hmm.
>
> Penny:Uh. . . Ducks pond in the summertime. Mmm, riding the subway.
>
> Dodge: Oh, **you lost me there**. Nobody misses the subway.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you%27ve+lost+me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You've lost me" normally means "I didn't follow that", or "I didn't understand that".

Here, guessing from the minimal context you've provided, I assume that Penny is mentioning things that she misses (in the sense that they're missing in her current life, or she's sad that they're no longer there). Dodge's reply is not literally "I didn't understand you", but used to mean "That's silly", because "nobody misses the subway".